# Nuxt 3 SCSS internal error after every save or new SCSS file create

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have fresh nuxt3 project and I try to add some scss styling. I have two issues i want to discuss:

1. After every save i have some error in terminal but application still works and error not appear on website. Error down below.
2. When i add some new file in scss folder and try to import it to my main.scss by @use I have same error but this one appear on website and i have to use yarn dev again.

#### Error for no. 1

```
 ERROR  Internal server error: [sass] expected "{".                                                                                                                                                                                                  11:50:07
  ╷
9 │ </script>
  │          ^
  ╵
  pages\index.vue 9:10  root stylesheet
  Plugin: vite:css
  File: F:\Projekty\BearDash\Website\pages\index.vue:9:10
```

#### package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-beta.10",
    "nuxt": "^3.3.3",
    "sass": "^1.62.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  }
```

#### nuxt.config.js

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: [
    "~/assets/scss/main.scss",
  ],
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: '@use "@/assets/scss/_variables.scss" as *;'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this working on a Nuxt 3 site. You have a few configuration differences that I think are causing issues. Try this:

**package.json**

You need sass-loader.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.59.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0"
}
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
css: ['@/assets/scss/main.scss'],
vite: {
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: '@import "@/assets/scss/_variables.scss";',
      },
    },
  },
},
```